# Can´t find the correct class for string methods in Godot

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am trying to make my program read and edit text. I was trying to use the `Position=find ( String , 0 )` method but I get the error:

> The method "find" isn't declared in the current class.

I have tried different classes but I cant find the correct one.
Which would that be?
How may I find the correct class in the future?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`find`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_string.html#class-string-method-find) is in the `String` class.

From the documentation:

> `int find ( String what, int from=0 )`
>
> Finds the first occurrence of a substring. Returns the starting position of the substring or -1 if not found.

So what happens?

When you do `Position = find(String, 0)` You are calling `find` from which ever class your code is inside, not from `String`.

Furthermore, I only see one `String` there… Which `String` do you want to find in which one? You need two. Yes, `find` only takes one `String`, but it is an **instance method**, not a static method. You are meant to call it on the one you want to search, like this:

```
var position := string_in_which_you_are_looking.find(string_you_are_looking_for, 0)
```

Comment: As an addition: it is always useful to have the Godot documentation up when coding.